# How to set width of a progress view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

Is there any normal way to set one simple thing as it is a width of a UIProgressView?
Most of the questions on the web are about the height, but I cannot believe that there is no normal way of setting weight programmatically?

Does anyone has any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean *width* or *weight*? I am not sure that you're actually asking this (because this is so obvious), but all view sizes are basically controlled by `frame` property. You can control width using the property, and it's working well.

AFAIK, there's no such weight stuff in progress-view.